# An example of a bounded countably infinite subset of the real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

I've been trying to think of an example of bounded, countably infinite subset of the real numbers.  However, knowing that countably infinite means can be put into 1-1 correspondence with the naturals, this doesn't seem intuitively obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

$$\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$$

Comment: Why am I so dumb?

Comment: @user55511: It’s fine. Don’t be so hard on yourself. Everyone has his or her own moments. :)

Comment: @user55511: We’ve all known that feeling a time or two; don’t worry about it too much.

Comment: Any particular reason why choose positive integers rather than natural numbers?

Comment: @DahnJahn well $1/0$ would be a problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PhilipJF Are you implying that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @ChristianMann yes.  Otherwise $\mathbb{N}$ is not a monoid under addition.  For me, $\mathbb{N}$ is the smallest set such that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n + 1 \in \mathbb{N}$.  It is only natural for the "point" here to be $0$ and not $1$, since *addition* is primitively recursive.

Comment: Alright, if that is the definition of natural numbers you use, then it makes absolute sense, thanks.

Comment: @user55511: Maybe lack of sleep? =P It certainly affects me!

Comment: @DahnJahn: $0\in\Bbb N$, and I didn’t want to clutter up the example by writing $\left\{\frac1{n+1}:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$.

Answer (score 15):

The set of rationals contained in $ [0,1] $ is another example.

**Addendum**

If you start off with any countably infinite set $ S \subseteq (- \infty,\infty) $ that is *unbounded*, then there is a quick way out. The inverse tangent function $ \tan^{-1} $ maps $ (- \infty,\infty) $ bijectively to the bounded interval $ \left( - \dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) $, so the image $ {\tan^{-1}}[S] $ is a bounded and countably infinite set. :)

Answer (score 10):

$$\mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b]$$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $a<b$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $A = \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ where $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3, ... \}$.

$A$ is bounded between 0 and 1, and has an obvious bijection with $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 5):

$\left\{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

- It's bounded in $(0,1]$
- It corresponds to $\mathbb{N}$ by $\varphi(n)=\frac{1}{n}$